# quotient space with usual topology

Tags: general-topology

let be $X$ be a closed with the usual topology, $C \subset X$ a closed interval.  then the quotient space $X / C$ is homeomorhpic to the interval $X$ \ $ C$ with the usual topology?

Comment: Are you asking this as a question/exercise to prove? What have you tried?

Comment: what is the usual topology? the subspace topology inherited by $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I guess i have to find a map between the two such as it pleases one of the conditions to be an homeomorphism, but dunno how. @Zest yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to define the continous surjective map $f\colon [0,5] \to [0,4]$ given by $$f(t) = \begin{cases} t \ &, t \le 4 \\ 4 \ &, t \ge 4 \end{cases}$$ Observe that $f$ is closed since $f$ is the identity on the subspace $[0,4]$ and constant on $[4,5]$.

Now, since $f$ is constant on the subspace $[4,5]$, it factors through $$\overline{f}\colon [0,5]\Big/[4,5] \to [0,4]$$

which is a homeomorphism since $f$ is a quotient map.